# Independence of unions of indepent events

Tags: probability-theory, independence

Is there a known lemma that claims that for a set of independent events, any unions over them (where an event can occur only in a single union) are also independent?

EDIT: We can assume that any combination of events are independent

Comment: $A\cup B$ and $B\cup C$ will usually not be independent

Comment: Thanks. Forgot to mention that an event can occur only in a single union. I'll edit my question

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by this. Do you perhaps mean to ask whether the following is true: "if $A,B$ are independent of $C,$ then $A\cup B$ is independent of $C$"? This is true.

Comment: Expanding on Ride's point: there are different definitions for 'a set of independent events'.  Are we assuming that the events are pairwise independent or a stronger condition?

Comment: Yes. But is it trivial to claim the same for any number of events? E.g. if $A,B,C,D,E$ are independent, then $A \cup  B$ is independent of  $C \cup D \cup E$

Comment: @DMath, A stronger condition: We can assume that any combination of events are independent

Answer (score 0):

Given two fair coin tosses, we have events $A=$ first coin is H, $B=$ second coin is H, $C=$ both coins show the same. Then $A,B,C$ are **pairwise independent.** Yet $A\cup B$ and $C$ are not independent: $P((A\cup B)\cap C)=\frac14\ne \frac34\cdot \frac12=P(A\cup B)\cdot P(C)$.

On the other hand, if the given events are **mutually independent**, i.e., the probability of *any* intersection of event is the product of the individual probabilities, then the probability of any logical combination of those events is just as you might (perhaps naively) think it is, i.e., 
$$ P((A\cup B)\cap C)=(1-(1-P(A))(1-P(B)))\cdot P(C)$$
and consequently, we have independence between $A\cup B$ and $C$, for example.
The reason is that you can expand everything into disjoint unions of intersections over all events or their complements; e.g.,
$$(A\cup B)\cap C=(A\cap B\cap C)\cup(A^c\cap B\cap C)\cup (A\cap B^c\cap C).  $$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Some comments:
(1) Could you clarify why does $$ P((A\cup B)\cap C)=(1-(1-P(A))(1-P(B)))\cdot P(C)$$ means that $(A\cup B)$ are independent of C? There's also an alternative explanation: $$P((A\cup B)\cap C) = P((A\cap C) \cup (B\cap C)) = P(A\cap C) + (B\cap C) - P((A\cap B \cap C) = P(C)\cdot(P(A) + (B) - P((A\cap B)) = P(C)\cdot P(A\cup B) $$. (2) I'm still not sure it can be trivially extended to any number of events. Could you elaborate on that?